# Multiple Markers In Google Maps Api Cannot read property 'lat' of undefined

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have an array of objects which I am placing markers for on the map. The Items are all being retrieved however the I am receiving the error of "Cannot read property 'lat' of undefined" on the  "bounds.extend(myLatLng[i]);"
can you see the reason why

```
function _studentsNearBySuccess(data) {
                    vm.notify(function () {
                        vm.studentsNearBy = data.items;
                        for (var i = 0; i < vm.studentsNearBy.length; i++) {
                            var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(vm.studentsNearBy[i].latitude, vm.studentsNearBy[i].longitude);
                            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
                            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                position: myLatLng[i],
                                title: 'Student Near By named ' + vm.studentsNearBy[i].firstName,
                            });
                            bounds.extend(myLatLng[i]);
                            var mapOptions = {
                                zoom: 10,
                                center: myLatLng
                            }
                            vm.map = new google.maps.Map($('#map-canvas')[0], mapOptions);
                            marker.setMap(vm.map)

                            vm.map.fitBounds(bounds);

                            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                                content: vm.studentsNearBy[i].firstName + vm.studentsNearBy[i].lastName + vm.studentsNearBy[i].email
                            });
                        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You create `myLatLng` as a single LatLng, when you do:

```
var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(vm.studentsNearBy[i].latitude, vm.studentsNearBy[i].longitude);
```

However you then try and refer to it as if it were an array of LatLngs when you do:

```
position: myLatLng[i],
```

and

```
bounds.extend(myLatLng[i]);
```

It's not an array.  Just change both of those to:

```
position: myLatLng,
```

and

```
bounds.extend(myLatLng);
```

**Update:** added a new version of your function. It looks like you're creating a new map for every single marker.  I'm assuming you only want 1 map, not one for each student?  And moved the code that creates the LatLngBounds and then makes the map fit those bounds, outside of the loop.  You still extend the bounds within the loop.

```
function _studentsNearBySuccess(data) {
    vm.notify(function () {
        vm.studentsNearBy = data.items;
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 10,
            center: myLatLng
        }
        vm.map = new google.maps.Map($('#map-canvas')[0], mapOptions);

        for (var i = 0; i < vm.studentsNearBy.length; i++) {
            var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(vm.studentsNearBy[i].latitude, vm.studentsNearBy[i].longitude);

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: vm.map,
                position: myLatLng,
                title: 'Student Near By named ' + vm.studentsNearBy[i].firstName,
            });
            bounds.extend(myLatLng);

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: vm.studentsNearBy[i].firstName + vm.studentsNearBy[i].lastName + vm.studentsNearBy[i].email
            });
        }

        vm.map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Thats the solution for that solution fixed the initial problem. Much appreciated. One more problem I am running into is that the map is only displaying the marker on my last item in the array instead of displaying all of them. Do you know why this is?

Comment: All the markers now appear! However what it currently does is it centers to the last image in the array without taking any other markers into account. Even though they are on the map

Comment: That's a whole new question!... the problem is you're creating a new LatLngBounds on every iteration of the loop.  You extend it to just that one marker, then fit the map to whatever that is.  You need to create the LatLngBounds **before** your loop, extend it with every marker **in** the loop, then fit the map to those bounds **after** the loop.  I'll adjust my answer to cover all this too.